# Failure to animate a g element in SVG by animating its "top" property

Tags: html, css, animation, svg, figma

So, if you check the fiddle, (https://jsfiddle.net/xXnikosXx/6jx2rpsf/3/)
I have an SVG image, with a couple of objects, and a mask. It's masking the text (colorful lines) which are hidden below it, and the plan was to animate their top position to make the text from below appear and the text from the top to disappear, to make a text scrolling effect. The text without the mask is shown in the image below, in case it helps.
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JY4Xw.png)
I thought the text would appear when the animation occurs, but it doesnt (if you remove the mask, the text is shown and animated properly but they layers are wrong so the text appears above everything else)

I cant figure out a way to make the text animate properly using the mask, is there something i can use instead of the mask to get the same result, but without the text issue?

relevant code:

```
<mask id="mask0" mask-type="alpha" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="354" y="174" width="733" height="344">
  <rect id="laptop-screen-front" x="354" y="174" width="733" height="344" fill="white" />
</mask>
<g mask="url(#mask0)">

<!-- some of the lines that represent text: -->
<g id="text-lines">
  <line id="Line 3" x1="408" y1="194.5" x2="433" y2="194.5" stroke="#E06C60" stroke-width="5" />
  <line id="Line 23" x1="438" y1="194.5" x2="463" y2="194.5" stroke="#D18C4C" stroke-width="5" />
  <line id="Line 35" x1="469" y1="194.5" x2="542" y2="194.5" stroke="#7BC379" stroke-width="5" />
  <line id="Line 36" x1="469" y1="209.5" x2="525" y2="209.5" stroke="#7BC379" stroke-width="5" />
</g>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I see what's wrong with the fiddle and the example code in the question itself does not animate the mask.

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't animate the mask. It attempts to animate the position of the text-lines g element. But SVG is not HTML. It is its own thing and doesn't support many common CSS properties: e.g. most relevant for you - there is no "top" property in SVG. The easiest way to do what you want is to get rid of all the CSS animations, and add a transform and a SMIL animation directly into the following part of the SVG.

```
 <g mask="url(#mask0)">
    <g id="text-lines" transform="translate(0 0)">
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" values="0 0; 0 -150; 0 0" dur="11s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <line id="Line 3" x1="408" .... etc.
```

BTW - one of the reasons to use transforms for animation is that browsers can often optimize things by doing the animation on the GPU - so it's better than viewBox or top animations.

Answer (score 1):

2 methods:

1. with SMIL

```css
svg#parent {
  background-color: rgba(100, 148, 237, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<svg id="parent" width="200" height="100" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="180" height="20" fill="white"  />
  <svg  x="10" y="10" width="180" height="20" viewBox="0 0 180 20" >
    <text x="20" y="15" > hello </text>
    <text x="20" y="35" > world </text>
    <animate attributeName="viewBox" 
       values="0 0 180 20; 0 20 180 20; 0 0 180 20" 
       begin="1s" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </svg>
</svg>
```

2. with javascript - requestAnimationFrame

```js
(function()
  {
  const
    svgInside = document.querySelector('#insideSVG')
  , moving    = .7 // change the value to slow down or speed up
    ;
  let 
    stepVal = moving
  , stepPos = 0
    ;
  requestAnimationFrame(step)
    ;
  function step()
    {
    stepPos += stepVal

    if (stepPos<=0)  stepVal = moving
    if (stepPos>=20) stepVal = -moving

    svgInside.setAttribute('viewBox',`0 ${stepPos} 180 20`)
  
    requestAnimationFrame(step)
    }
  }
)()
```

```css
svg#parent {
  background-color: rgba(100, 148, 237, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<svg id="parent" width="200" height="100" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="180" height="20" fill="white" />
  <svg  x="10" y="10" width="180" height="20" viewBox="0 0 180 20"
        id="insideSVG" >
    <text x="20" y="15" > hello </text>
    <text x="20" y="35" > world </text>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

For your SVG the values should be around:

```
<svg  x="354" y="174" width="733" height="344" viewBox="354 174 733 344" >
   <line x1="419" y1="187.5" ..... />

/.../

   <animate attributeName="viewBox" 
     values="354 174 733 344; 354 520 733 344; 354 174 733 344" 
      begin="1s" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
</svg>
```

> how does `<animate>` work ?
> – Paul LeBeau

the mdn documentation is quite complete:  :

- [SVG animation with SMIL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_animation_with_SMIL)
- [`<animate>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animate)

do not hesitate to consult the links to additional information pages

[but if you want a general vision of the animation possibilities of your SVGs, the Wikipedia page is ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVG_animation)

There is even a part showing the use of the [requestAnimationFrame()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame), which I am using here.

PS:The Whitesmith style has been around since 1978, and no, I don't use it for aesthetic reasons but because it checks that the right pairs of braces frame the right pieces of code. For the same reasons, I put the commas in front of data lines (they are invisible [and often forgotten] at the end of the line), as well as the column alignment (both in a similar way used in Haskell)
<sub>No, the K&R is not a foolproof style, nor is it more legitimate than any other.</sub>

Comment: This answer could be improved with some explanation

Comment: @Sean it is only a few lines of code that are not very complicated ... I will be ok to add explanations but on what?

Comment: For example: How do each of these work?  What does `<animate>` do?  Why does animating `viewBox` work?  How did you derive those animation `value`s?  What does each line of the javascript do?  etc.  You also have a very unusual JS indentation style. Reformatting in a more regular style may aid understanding of the code.